# Python 3.3 Bottle Image Upload Not Returning

Tags: python, ajax, bottle

I am using Python 3.3 with Bottle.

My web page uses AJAX to make a crossdomain call to my Bottle web services. The route in question is /imageSave. It's being passed an image in the POST call instead of just text. The route was being hit and it was saving the image, but for some strange reason it wasn't returning the string.

All the other routes work and return correct JSONP formatted content, so I'm not sure what is different about this function.

The malfunctioning route:

```
    @post('/imageSave')
    def imageSave():
        response.content_type = "application/json"
        callback = request.query.callback
        upload = request.files.get('fileInput')
        returnJson = {}

        if upload is not None:
            name, ext = os.path.splitext(upload.filename)

            if ext not in ('.png','.jpg','.jpeg'):
                print("File extension not allowed.")

            save_path = "C:/uploads"
            if not os.path.exists(save_path):
                os.makedirs(save_path)
            dynFileName = "Img_"+str(strftime("%Y.%m.%d.%H.%M.%S", gmtime()))+str(ext)
            file_path = "{path}/{file}".format(path=save_path, file=dynFileName)
            print(dynFileName)
            upload.save(file_path)

        #returnJson = json.dumps({"fileName":dynFileName})
        returnJson["fileName"]= str(dynFileName)
        print(returnJson)

        return str(returnJson)
```

Here is another route that is working:

```
    @route('/imageDelete', method="POST")
    def imageDelete():
        response.content_type = "application/json"
        callback = request.query.callback
        file_name = request.query.file_name

        os.remove(pathToImage+"/uploads/"+str(file_name))

        returnJson = {"deleted":"true"}
```

Comment: Have you tried returning the `dict` (instead of converting it to `str`)?  `return returnJson`